# respond.js crashes IE9 in IE8 or IE7 mode

Tags: javascript, media-queries, polyfills

I'm doing some browser testing in IE9, which comes with the great feature to run in IE8 and IE7 mode.

I'm testing css3 media queries support and I'm using respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) or css3-mediaqueries-js (http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) for that.

Both of them crash IE9 when putting them in IE8 or IE7 mode. When I exclude the libraries above, IE behaves just fine, but off course without media query polyfill.

Is there a reason why this is crashing? I was thinking that IE9 might not have a matching IE8 JS engine or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for Respond.js, they state that there is a known issue with using @font-face inside media queries for IE 8 and below. Could you verify that?.

If this is the case, you must take the @font-face outside of the media query